# Перестала работать программа, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Когда запускаешь моделирование маятник перестает отображаться

```js
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.lineWidth = 3;

var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

var α = 0;
var ω = 0;
var m = 0.1;
var g = 9.8;
var l = 0.5;
var kf = 1;
var M = 0;
var linelenght = 0;
var kp = 0;
var ki = 0;
var kd = 0;
var P = 0,
  I = 0,
  D = 0;
var error = 0,
  prevError = 0,
  dError = 0;

var isSimulationOn = false;
var lastT = performance.now();

function $(selector, context) {
  return (context || document).querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector, context) {
  return Array.from((context || document).querySelectorAll(selector));
}

function draw(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  var dt = Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);
  lastT = t;

  if (isSimulationOn) {
    error = linelenght - α + Math.PI / 2;
    dError = error - prevError;
    P = error;
    I += error * Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);
    D = dError / Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);
    prevError = error;
    M = (kp * P) + (ki * I) + (kd * D);

    α += dt * ω;
    ω += dt * (-g / l * Math.sin(α) - kf * l / m * ω * ω * Math.sign(ω) + M / m / l / l);

    angle += α * dt;

  }

  var angle = α + Math.PI / 2;
  var size = Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  var ox = WIDTH / 2;
  var rPend = size * 0.45 * Math.tanh(0.5 * l);
  var rBall = size * 0.05 * Math.tanh(0.5 * m);
  var x = ox - rPend * Math.cos(angle);
  var y = rPend * Math.sin(angle) + 2;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, rBall, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();

  context.moveTo(0, 2);
  context.lineTo(WIDTH, 2);
  context.moveTo(ox, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.stroke();
}

function updateVariables() {
  $$(".quantity-block input[name]").forEach(function(input) {
    assignVariable(input.name, input.value);
  });
}

function assignVariable(name, value) {
  if (name in window) {
    window[name] = Number(value);
    if (name === "α") ω = 0;
    if (name === "l" || name === "m") window[name] = Math.max(0.01, window[name]);
  }
}

function toggleSimulation() {
  isSimulationOn = !isSimulationOn;
  $(".button").textContent = isSimulationOn ? "Остановить" : "Моделировать"
  updateVariables();
}

$(".quantity-block").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  if (input.matches("input[name]")) {
    assignVariable(input.name, input.value);
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
toggleSimulation();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 50em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f5f5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.quantity-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.quantity-block label {
  text-align: start;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

input,
select,
button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>

<div class="quantity-block">

  <label>Начальный угол маятника</label>
  <input name="α" type="range" value="1" min="-1.57" max="1.57" step="any">

  <label> Масса шарика</label>
  <input name="m" type="number" value="1" step="any">

  <label>Длина маятника</label>
  <input name="l" type="number" value="0.5" step="any">

  <label>Коэффициент сопротивления окружающей среды</label>
  <input name="kf" type="number" value="2" step="any">

  <label>П-контролер:</label>
  <input name="p" type="number" step="1" value="1000" id="kp" />

  <label>И-контролер:</label>
  <input name="i" type="number" step="1" value="100" id="ki" />

  <label>Д-контролер:</label>
  <input name="d" type="number" step="1" value="30" id="kd" />

  <label>Требуемый угол:</label>
  <input name="linelenght" type="number" step="5" value="60" id="target">
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="toggleSimulation();">Моделировать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в присваивании `lastT = t;` до вычислений, где важна разница между этими переменными.

В итоге получается `t - lastT == 0`, при делении на него получается `Infinity`, далее это число умножается на 0, получается `NaN` и ломаются все дальнейшие расчеты.

Для решения достаточно перенести присвоение `lastT` в конец функции.

```js
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.lineWidth = 3;

var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

var α = 0;
var ω = 0;
var m = 0.1;
var g = 9.8;
var l = 0.5;
var kf = 1;
var M = 0;
var linelenght = 0;
var kp = 0;
var ki = 0;
var kd = 0;
var P = 0,
  I = 0,
  D = 0;
var error = 0,
  prevError = 0,
  dError = 0;

var isSimulationOn = false;
var lastT = performance.now();

function $(selector, context) {
  return (context || document).querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector, context) {
  return Array.from((context || document).querySelectorAll(selector));
}

function draw(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  var dt = Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);

  if (isSimulationOn) {
    error = linelenght - α + Math.PI / 2;
    dError = error - prevError;
    P = error;
    I += error * Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);
    D = dError / Math.min(1 / 24, (t - lastT) / 1000);
    prevError = error;
    M = (kp * P) + (ki * I) + (kd * D);

    α += dt * ω;

    ω += dt * (-g / l * Math.sin(α) - kf * l / m * ω * ω * Math.sign(ω) + M / m / l / l);

    angle += α * dt;
  }

  var angle = α + Math.PI / 2;
  var size = Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  var ox = WIDTH / 2;
  var rPend = size * 0.45 * Math.tanh(0.5 * l);
  var rBall = size * 0.05 * Math.tanh(0.5 * m);
  var x = ox - rPend * Math.cos(angle);
  var y = rPend * Math.sin(angle) + 2;
  lastT = t;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, rBall, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 2);
  context.lineTo(WIDTH, 2);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(ox, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.stroke();
}

function updateVariables() {
  $$(".quantity-block input[name]").forEach(function(input) {
    assignVariable(input.name, input.value);
  });
}

function assignVariable(name, value) {
  if (name in window) {
    window[name] = Number(value);
    if (name === "α") ω = 0;
    if (name === "l" || name === "m") window[name] = Math.max(0.01, window[name]);
  }
}

function toggleSimulation() {
  isSimulationOn = !isSimulationOn;
  $(".button").textContent = isSimulationOn ? "Остановить" : "Моделировать"
  updateVariables();
}

$(".quantity-block").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  if (input.matches("input[name]")) {
    assignVariable(input.name, input.value);
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
toggleSimulation();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 50em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f5f5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.quantity-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.quantity-block label {
  text-align: start;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

input,
select,
button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>

<div class="quantity-block">

  <label>Начальный угол маятника</label>
  <input name="α" type="range" value="1" min="-1.57" max="1.57" step="any">

  <label> Масса шарика</label>
  <input name="m" type="number" value="1" step="any">

  <label>Длина маятника</label>
  <input name="l" type="number" value="0.5" step="any">

  <label>Коэффициент сопротивления окружающей среды</label>
  <input name="kf" type="number" value="2" step="any">

  <label>П-контролер:</label>
  <input name="p" type="number" step="1" value="1000" id="kp" />

  <label>И-контролер:</label>
  <input name="i" type="number" step="1" value="100" id="ki" />

  <label>Д-контролер:</label>
  <input name="d" type="number" step="1" value="30" id="kd" />

  <label>Требуемый угол:</label>
  <input name="linelenght" type="number" step="5" value="60" id="target">
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="toggleSimulation();">Моделировать</button>
```

Comment: но он не держит установленный угол который должен, не подскажите в чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: @ell, что значит _не держит установленный угол_? Проверяй используемые формулы и какие значения ты в них передаешь